# how does functions that return function work?

Tags: javascript

I expect that every time I call the function it will pass 1 as the value of seed parameter and so that value = 1 * 16807 in returned function 
so the result of every call will be 16807 
I don't understand how this function work

```
 function pseudoRandom(seed) {
  let value = seed;

  return function() {
    value = value * 16807;
    return value;
  }
}

let generator = pseudoRandom(1);
alert(generator()); // 16807
alert(generator()); // 282475249
alert(generator()); // 1622650073
```

Comment: Because it updates value.... `value = value * 16807;` <-- no longer seed

Comment: When you call `generator()` the previous value of `value` is used, not of `seed`.

Comment: Reading this will be helpful: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Closures

Comment: It looks like this is homework from https://javascript.info/task/pseudo-random-generator and your implementation is buggy: for the third call to equal `1622650073` you need to use the prescribed algorithm: `value = value * 16807 % 2147483647`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you set `value = value * 16807`, it changes the the variable in `generator`'s closure, so each call to `generator` sees the value set by the last call.

---

Here's a simplified version of how closures work:

When you run `pseudoRandom(1)`, you create a closure. Basically, the closure is the combination of the function returned by `pseudoRandom` and `pseudoRandom`'s local variables. When you call that closure, it updates `value` in the closure's local variables, so future calls see a different value.

And remember that each time you call `pseudoRandom`, you create a new closure, with its own local variables, which lets the seeding work correctly.

I recommend reading at least the first 3 or so sections of [Mozilla's page on the topic](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Closures) to build a better understanding of how closures work and why they are useful.

Answer (score 0):

This is a scope issue. Change the code to return

```
return function() {
    return value * 16807;
}
```

or rename the variable in the return function from value to var myValue (for example). In your existing code you are updating value in the outer method. See closures:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Closures#Closure

Answer (score 0):

If you do not assign back to `value`, every time result will be the same 16807.

```
function pseudoRandom(seed) {
  let value = seed;

  return function() {
    // value = value * 16807;
    return value * 16807;
  }
}
```

Since you are modifying the `value` after multiplying with 16807, everytime you call generator() it will be 1 * 16807, 1 * 16807 * 16807, 1 * 16807 * 16807 * 16807 and so on.